# Compiler tells me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

The console tell me that at (28,22) it "cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'bool'" but at that place I am using a variable that is a char and I am not trying to convert it into a bool.  It is this spot in the code 
else if (ch2 = 'c')
the exact place is between the '(' and 'c'.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
using System;

public class EntranceChecking
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        char ch1, ch2;// Input character
        bool guess = false; // Flag that signals when the loop should terminate --
        //   that is, when 'c' followed by 's' has been input.
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou have before you a closed door.");
        Console.WriteLine("You must give the correct password to enter");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a character : ");
        ch1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;


        // Insert a loop that keeps reading and processing characters
        // until the user inputs the character 'c' followed by the
        // character 's' (if ever).

         while (!guess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a character : ");
            ch2 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if ((ch1 == 'c') && (ch2 == 's'))
                guess = true;
            else if (ch2 = 'c')
            {
                ch1 = 'c';
                break;
            }
            else
                ch1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        }

        // Open the door.
        Console.Write("The door opens. Congratulations!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
else if (ch2 = 'c')
```

for

```
else if (ch2 == 'c')
```

because if() expects a boolean, if you use the `==` operartor it will return a boolean

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid now.  Must have missed it from being so tired heh.  Thank you for the help!